# ember.js difference routes folder and router.js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-rails

I'm trying to make a project in rails and ember.js through the ember-rails gem.
I made a `rails generate ember:bootstrap` and I'm observing the tree it created under `assets/javascripts`.

I can't understand what is the difference between things I have to put inside the `routes.js` file at top level, and in files inside the `/routes` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the routes.js file at the the top, you will define your routes and resources eg:

You can use this **[rails app](https://github.com/mankind/ember-app/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/app_router.js)** as guide. The code I use in this answer came from that repo.

```
EmBlog.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", {path: '/posts'}, function(){
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', {path: '/:post_id'}) ;
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:post_id/edit'});

 });
});
```

If you want **to customize any of those routes or resources**, then you **create a new file in /routes folder**. For example if we want to customize **the show route** by **defining an event to delete a post** in that router and to also **customize what data is returned** using the **model hook**, then we would need to create a file in  **[/ routes / posts / show_route.js](https://github.com/mankind/ember-app/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/routes/posts/show_route.js)** and add our code there:

```
EmBlog.PostsShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

 model: function(params) {
  return EmBlog.Post.find(params.post_id);
 },

 setupController: function(controller, model){
  controller.set('content', model);
 },

 events: {
  destroyPost: function(post) {
   post.deleteRecord();
   post.get('store').commit();
   this.transitionTo('posts');
  }
 }

});
```

The idea of splitting the route is to ensure it doesn't get too big or filled with 100's of lines of code. If you prefer defining both the top level routes and their customization in thesame file. You can. Here is **[another rails app](https://github.com/bcardarella/ember-railsapi/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/routes.js.coffee)** that does just that.